# Javascript forEach not working when looping through JSON parsed XML with 1 childnode?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<output>
  <count>
  </count>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <element1></element1>
      <element2></element2>
      <element3></element3>
      <element4></element4>
    </row>
    <row>
      <element1></element1>
      <element2></element2>
      <element3></element3>
      <element4></element4>
    </row>
  </rows>
</output>
```

I request the file via AJAX from PHP and load it (response) into a variable:

```
var xml=JSON.parse(response);
```

Next, I want to loop through it to grab data. I noticed that when the amount of row nodes is > 1, I can do for example:

```
var list=[];
xml.output.list.rows.row.forEach(function(item)
{
   list.push(item.element1);
});
```

However, when there is only 1 row node, this forEach does not work. Can someone explain to me why and/or provide an alternative solution/approach for iterating through such a file?

Comment: XML ***is not*** JSON ?

Comment: you should show the JSON, not the xml

Comment: I don't know the object type of row, how can I check? I'm building up a div from the data in the element nodes (which can also have child nodes). My solution for now is to check how many row childs there are; if only 1 I just grab it directly, if more than 1 I iterate through them via forEach. This works, but is not very efficiently in my opinion.

Comment: @ILE You probably want to include a sample of the XML where there is only one row.  Further, we have to assume that you have some XML -> JSON conversion happening here, and it may be configured to convert arrays with one element like this

Answer (score 0):

Now checking amount of child nodes with

```
for (childnode in xml.output.rows.row)
```

which allows me to access data of each childnode regardless of amount of nodex.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of parsing XML into JSON, I recommend you to parsing it into a doc. Following is an example code

```
var testXML = "<output><count></count><rows><row><element1>asd</element1></row><row><element1>zz</element1><element2>xx</element2></row></rows></output>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(testXML, "text/xml");
var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName('row');

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    console.log(rows[0]);
};
```

It prints out 2 rows inside the selected rows. Please let me know if you need extra explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing the parsing method is not really an option considering the progress so far..